# Automatically change sound output/input to bluetooth speaker/headphones

Tags: macos, bluetooth, big-sur, headphones, speakers

I have a bluetooth speaker and a couple of bluetooth headphones. I would like macOS to automatically use them for sound output/input when they connect. At the moment I have to go into Sound settings and manually select which speaker I want to use.

How can I make macOS automatically output and input sound on the most recently connected bluetooth speaker/headphones?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [SoundControl](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/) to do this. It’s not free, but significantly expands your volume control in MacOS. They offer a trial, so I wouldn’t let the “non-free-ness” dissuade you.

You could then use the MIDI controls in MacOS to create the appropriate aggregate/multi-output devices you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).